# Connecting Raspberry Pi Zero W to wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, troubleshooting

I've just set up a Raspberry Pi Zero W - my first Raspberry Pi.  I've loaded Raspbian into it without trouble, but I can't connect it to WiFi.  It can find my home network easily, and lets me key in my network password, but there's no response - no connection, no error message.  It just doesn't connect.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some network setting I need to change?

This doesn't seem to be the same as setting up headless networking - I've followed the instructions from the Foundation Guidelines, namely selecting the network and keying in the password - but it's just not connecting.  I've been advised to check if I have N2 Network Interface...can someone explain how to check that?

Comment: Is your wifi 2.4GHz ?

Comment: I think so.  Never had any issues connecting phones and laptops to it.

Comment: phones and laptops for many years have 5GHz wifi - so that proves nothing - however, since your Pi "finds" the network, then there's no doubt it's a 2.4GHz one ... I take it you are using full raspbian and use some desktop thing to connect to wifi (forgive my ignorance, never ever used a pi as a Desktop)

Comment: Yeah, I plug the Pi into a TV and use the desktop from Raspian to try connecting to WiFi.

Comment: I don't think so.  That thread directed me to the Foundation Guidelines, which only told me to select the network and then type in the password.  That's what I've been doing - it just doesn't connect afterwards.  Someone else has suggested I confirm I have N2 Network Interface.  I'm a beginner, so I don't know what that is.  Can anyone explain?